# Use threads in a ref class form c++ to make parallel works

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio, winforms, parallel-processing, c++-cli

I am currently working in an HMI. I have to send a message and wait for a response. But if i use a while loop to wait for the response, my HMI stops the interactions waiting for the while loop's end.

I tried to use threads, and I tried to make a threads function in the HMI ref class to execute the function which contains the while loop. But I don't know how to do it. can you help me with that, or give me another way to make parallel work? Thanks

This is the code which contains the while loop from another class

```
bool Robot::waitArrival(char* at)
{
    char _status[256];
    strcpy(_status, "Going to ");
    strcat(_status, static_cast<char*>(at));
        do
    {
        this->handUpdates->lock();
        strcpy(this->status, this->handUpdates->getStatus());
        this->handUpdates->unlock();

        ArUtil::sleep(1000); //1s
    } while (strcmp(this->status, _status) == 0);

    strcpy(_status, "Arrived at ");
    strcat(_status, static_cast<char*>(at));

    if (strcmp(this->status, _status) == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

and this is my HMI. By clicking button3 I call the ctr_main() function in the Controller ref class, the ctr_main() function calls the waitArrival() function,

```
    private: System::Void button3_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        Thread t1(&Controleur::ctr_main);
    }
```

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but what is an IHM?

Comment: @parktomatomi I second that ... What is "an IHM"?

Comment: @parktomatomi  i changed to HMI, human-machine interface, it's just a winform

Comment: @walnut i just do

Comment: Hmm... what version of .NET are you using? Also, have you tried using `Thread.Sleep` instead of the 3rd party one you're using?

Comment: Using a thread is not a great idea if you don't know how to get started.  Instead use a Timer, its Tick event handler can call getStatus().  Keeping track of the robot state is usually best done with a state machine.

Comment: @parktomatomi i use v4.6.1, can u give me a code example please

Comment: @HansPassant can you give me a code example please

Comment: @HansPassant i think it's ok, i made Timer asking for the robot position and that make me able to interact with the HMI between the Timer steps, thanks